# encoding and rendering a (network) graph in python

Tags: python, numpy, graph, graph-theory

the code below does not render my graph.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pylab
import random
import scipy
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from pylab import *
from scipy import ndimage
def H(x,y,gamma):
    val = HenonMap(x,y,1,1,0.2,gamma)
    return val
def HenonIterate(x0,y0,n,gamma):
    (x,y) = H(x0,y0,gamma)
    for i in xrange (0,n):
        (x,y)=H(x,y,gamma)
        if (pow(x,2)) + (pow(y,2)) > 100:
            return i
    return n

def g():
    x2=1000
    y2=1000
    max=100
    u = zeros([x2,y2])
    for x in range(x2):
        for y in range(y2):
            y0= .01*y-5.0
            x0= -.01*x+5.0
            u[x][y] = HenonIterate(x0,y0,max,1.03)
        imshow(u)
        show()
```

Comment: How do you run the code? Nothing should show because you don't run any main method.

Comment: I run it using python shell. It's suppose to show a graph.

Comment: It doesn't because you don't *run* anything. You define a few functions but you don't actually run them.

Comment: also, where is HenonMap defined?

Comment: Have posted full code? And you may add "g()" at end of file.

Comment: Now im getting error code after posting g()

Answer (score 6):

From a look at your code, I'm not exactly sure what you had in mind so it's difficult for me to work directly with it; however, i can show you how to create graphs in python and render them in **Matplotlib**.

[Networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/index.html) is an excellent python library for generating graphs, analyzing them, and rendering them via Matplotlib or Graphviz.  For instance,

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as MPL
import networkx as NX                  # import networkx
```

You can create a graph in Networkx by importing a data file (Networkx has quite a modules to translate among formats) or by using one of Networkx' gtraph generators. To generate the graph shown below, i create a particular type of binomial random graph, ***erdos-renyi***.

To create a graph in Networkx, i just call the graph constructor and pass in the desired number of nodes and the edge creation probability.

```
G = NX.erdos_renyi_graph(10, .3)
```

Rendering this graph in Networkx is trivial--just call ***draw*** and pass in your graph. Behind the scenes, Network passes all data required for rendering your graph in Matplotlib (e.g., node position, style attributes, labels, etc.) and calls Matplotlib's ***plot*** method for you, passing all of this data in. The only interaction with Matplotlib required by the user is to call ***show*** or ***savefig*** to render it on screen or to a file, respectively.

```
NX.draw(G)
MPL.show()
```

If you want to generate the graph yourself then hand it over to Networkx to render via Matplotlib, that's also straightforward. For instance, below, i create a 5 x 5 **NumPy array** to represent an ***adjacency matrix*** (the most common format for representing sparse graph data):

```
>>> G = NP.random.randint(0, 2, 25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> G
  array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Now convert the NumPy array to a Networkx graph using the standard Networkx constructor for a directed graph, ***DiGraph***

```
>>> G1 = NX.DiGraph(G)

>>> len(G1.nodes())
      5
>>> type(G1)
      <class 'networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph'>
```

Instead of a directed graph, you can create an undirected graph from the adjacency matrix; just use the appropriate constructor, ***Graph***

```
>>> G2 = NX.Graph(G)
```

This graph is rendered in Matplotlib *exactly like* the one above--by calling Networkx' ***draw*** method then Matplotlib's ***show*** to render it on screen.

```
>>> NX.draw(G2)
>>> MPL.show()
```

[image]

Comment: While a nice introduction to `networkx`, I think that the OP misused the word _graph_. There is code to `imshow(u)` where `u` is a square array of floats which, to me, implies a heatmap of some kind. A second hint is that a Hénon map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A9non_map is a toy dynamical system that exhibits chaotic behaviors. The pictures on the wiki page suggest a 2D image map as well.

Comment: @Hooked just checked the OP; you're right. the Henon reference went right over my head though--thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @doug What if I wanted to use your adjacency matrix approach to build a grid network with something like `nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)`? In this case I need the positions to respect this line `pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )`, with edges coming from the adjacency matrix? The only constraint is that thre must be no disconnected nodes, and when the matrix is created, all `(i,j)` positions must have the same probability of landing a `1`. Feasible? Should I turn this into a proper question? Thanks!

Comment: How did you get it to show the node numbers in the plot?

Answer (score 0):

When you run this script, the `H(x,y,gamma)`, `HenonIterate(x0,y0,n,gamma)` and `g()` get defined. Thats all that happens.

If you want to run g() at the end of the script, add a `g()`.

It then complains that the `HenonMap` function is not defined. Do find a suitable implementation which takes in 6 parameters.